# Compare each file with their corresponding file in another folder in Python?

Tags: python

This code takes one shapefile, looks at its schema and compares it with another shapefile (its corresponding) in another location and prints their differences in their schemas.

```
pst_n=fiona.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\new\PST')#new pst
pst_o=fiona.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\old\PST')#old_pst
pst_n.schema
d1 = pst_n.schema['properties']
d2 = pst_o.schema['properties']

d1_items = set(d1.items())
d2_items = set(d2.items())
result = sorted([(k, 'd1', v) for k, v in d1_items if (k, v) not in d2_items] +
                [(k, 'd2', v) for k, v in d2_items if (k, v) not in d1_items])

result = [(k, v, d) for k, d, v in result]


pprint(result)
```

And shows the differences like that:

```
[('ADDRESS', 'int:4', 'd1'),
 ('ADDRESS', 'str:254', 'd2'),
 ('AREA', 'float:19.11', 'd2'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'int:4', 'd1'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'str:254', 'd2'),
 ('DESC_', 'str:254', 'd1'),
 ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9', 'd1'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:50', 'd1'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:12', 'd2'),
 ('LEN', 'float:19.11', 'd2')
```

This is done manually here. I want it to be done by searching in one main directory for the old versions of the files and comparing each in every subfolder of the other main directory with the corresponding new versions.

**What is the wanted result**

One main folder A with B,C,D... subfolders. This main folder has **new** under consideration files.**Most** of the subfolders have shps.

There is one other main folder though. Let's call it K with L,M,N.. subfolders.These subfolders are the corresponding from the other subfolders of the other folder with the **new** files.

The subfolders from **A** have the same names with the ones from **K** although **K** may have more that we don't need.

I want the user to insert the directory of the main `A` folder and read the first shp from the first subfolder (if it exists an shp there) then go to the other `old` main folder and check the corresponding subfolder, get the `shp` from there *and do some comparisons between them and print the results*(the italics parts i have already solved them)and then continue with the rest of the `new` folder's subfolders accordingly.If in one subfolder there is not an shp it should print:'folder name' has no shp. and continue with the rest.

There is this code for the initial collection:

```
import fiona
from pprint import pprint
import os
import fnmatch

def new_file_paths(rootdir):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
        if dirpath == rootdir: continue. # ignore files in the root
        yield dirpath, [os.path.join(dirpath, fname) for fname in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.shp')]
```

Here takes the two main directories that will compare:

```
rootdir_new = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a'
rootdir_old = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\k'

for directory, paths in new_file_paths(rootdir_new)):
    if not paths:
        print('{} is empty, no new files found'.format(directory))
        continue

    for path in paths:
        relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, rootdir_new)
        old_path = os.path.join(rootdir_old, relative_path)
        if not os.path.exists(old_path):
            # no corresponding old file
            print('No matching previous version of {}' 
                  'found, skipping'.format(relative_path))
            continue

        # compare `path` with `old_path`

        d1_items = set(path.items())
        d2_items = set(old_path.items())
        result = sorted([(k, 'd1', v) for k, v in d1_items if (k, v) not in d2_items] +
                        [(k, 'd2', v) for k, v in d2_items if (k, v) not ind1_items])

        result = [(k, v, d) for k, d, v in result]
```

The question is how to do the actual comparison of every pair with the same name in these two main directories and print the result for each? Like in the beginning but through the loop with no manual opening of the shapefiles?Just to chech them and print the results of the differences. Is this code performs as the idea in the text? i've been planning to make it work as the text but i can't.

files are here for testing:[http://www.mediafire.com/file/644y8e12pj9jrei/main_folders.zip](http://[http://www.mediafire.com/file/644y8e12pj9jrei/main_folders.zip][1])

Comment: I think you are almost there: You worked out how to compare two files and you can generate a list of all file paths to compare. Now take your "manual comparison" code above and plug it in right where you wrote `# compare 'path' with 'old_path'`.

Comment: the thing is that the manual part will not communicate with the 'iteration' in the loops.That's the missing part that can't fix

Comment: Just copy the code into the for loop and use `path` and `old_path` instead of the hard-coded strings.

Comment: i updated the code but it doesn't work.I can't understand what should i change.Make an answer to convey it.Check the extra code i put in the last piece,it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to open the files first, not compare the path strings. I put everything together in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to combine your two parts:

```
rootdir_new = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a'
rootdir_old = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\k'

for directory, paths in new_file_paths(rootdir_new)):
    if not paths:
        print('{} is empty, no new files found'.format(directory))
        continue

    for path in paths:
        relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, rootdir_new)
        old_path = os.path.join(rootdir_old, relative_path)
        if not os.path.exists(old_path):
            # no corresponding old file
            print('No matching previous version of {}' 
                  'found, skipping'.format(relative_path))
            continue

        # compare `path` with `old_path`

        pst_n=fiona.open(path) #new pst
        pst_o=fiona.open(old_path) #old_pst
        pst_n.schema
        d1 = pst_n.schema['properties']
        d2 = pst_o.schema['properties']

        d1_items = set(d1.items())
        d2_items = set(d2.items())
        result = sorted([(k, path, v) for k, v in d1_items if (k, v) not in d2_items] +
                        [(k, old_path, v) for k, v in d2_items if (k, v) not ind1_items])

        result = [(k, v, d) for k, d, v in result]
```

Comment: An improvement that i would need is to give the actual name of the shapefiles  that iterates and compares instead of d1 and d2 since will be a a lot of files so the user will  know which comparisons occur.

Comment: I edited my code accordingly. However, I believe that you should be able to figure out the details for yourself, e.g. you need to think about how to store and display your results.